# jquery dataTables dataTables.spanish.txt grails

Tags: grails, datatables

I'm new to grails (well, new to all programming), but after some research I decided to try groovy with grails.

Currently I'm struggling trying to use Data Tables with grails... I have the next initialization code for a DataTable, and it works very well on php, but when I plug it into my grails app, it automatically adds a level for the directory I specified for my dataTables.spanish.txt file, keeping my DataTable instance for being correctly initialized.

¿Does anyone knows how must I specify the directory for it to be fine on grails?

My file is at: /js/tbl/dataTables.spanish.txt

But when the server is started it parses de directory as Myapp/**project**/js/tbl/dataTables.spanish.txt

Project is the name of my domain class, and the views for that class are located in that folder... I would prefer to keep this file independent from the views, as I would like to use it for several views.

My code currently goes as follows (I had to comment the file's line to avoid the error):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bSortClasses": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"H"lf>t<"F"Tip>',
        "oTableTools": {
           "aButtons": [
                    {
                        "sExtends":    "csv",
                        "sButtonText": "Exportar"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, 100,-1], [10, 20, 50, 100,               "Todos"]],
            "iDisplayLength" : 20,
            "oLanguage": {
                             //"sUrl": "/js/tbl/dataTables.spanish.txt"
                }
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails works with the [Resources plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/) to organize js and css files. So the fist step is to declare the files needed by DataTables as a resource in your **ApplicationResources.groovy**

```
modules = {
  dataTables {
    resource url: '/js/tbl/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
    resource url: '/js/tbl/css/jquery.dataTables.css'
  }
}
```

After that you can require the module in your GSP

```
<r:require module="dataTables" />
```

And then declare the javascript that init your table.

```
<r:script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();
});
</r:script>
```

All working? Now you can edit the options of the dataTable to fit your needs. You stored the spanish txt file in js, so you will need to use resources to look at the location of the file when your app is running.

Change

```
"oLanguage": {
  "sUrl": "/js/tbl/dataTables.spanish.txt"
}
```

to

```
"oLanguage": {
  "sUrl": "${resource(dir: 'js/tbl/', file: 'dataTables.spanish.txt')}"
}
```

There's this [good screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=HCUJuGXZ9A0#!) that will show you how resources works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sérgio. This really puts me on track.